# Appium: Keep session active between tests

Tags: python, appium

I have two python scripts. In python1.py, it goes through the onboarding part of our app, and in python2.py, it goes through the rest of the app. My issue is that in order for python2 to work, the app needs to be on the screen that python1.py ends on. So what i'm looking for is how I can run python1.py, then run python2.py with the app in the same state as python1 left it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the "noReset" capability for the Appium server in your python2.py.

> noReset   Don’t reset app state before this session. Default false

If you set noReset=true in python2.py, you should have the app in the state that python1.py left it.

Check this for more info: http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?python#appium-server-capabilities

Comment: Because of the nature of our app, noReset didn't work. I ended up asking our iOS dev to add a command-line argument to the app so that I could pass that in via caps.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late. But I paste here my solution.

```
from appium.webdriver.errorhandler import MobileErrorHandler
from appium.webdriver.switch_to import MobileSwitchTo    
from appium import webdriver

class MyWebDriverAppium(webdriver.Remote):    

    def __init__(self, command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
             desired_capabilities=None, session_id=None):
        self.preserved_session_id = session_id

        self.error_handler = MobileErrorHandler()
        self._switch_to = MobileSwitchTo(self)

        # add new method to the `find_by_*` pantheon
        By.IOS_UIAUTOMATION = MobileBy.IOS_UIAUTOMATION
        By.IOS_PREDICATE = MobileBy.IOS_PREDICATE
        By.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR = MobileBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR
        By.ACCESSIBILITY_ID = MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID
        super(MyWebDriverAppium, self).__init__(command_executor, desired_capabilities)

    def start_session(self, desired_capabilities, browser_profile=None):
        if self.preserved_session_id:
            self.command_executor._commands['getSession'] = ('GET', '/session/$sessionId')
            self.session_id = self.preserved_session_id
            response = self.execute('getSession', {'sessionId ': self.session_id})
            self.session_id = response['sessionId']
            self.capabilities = response['value']
            self.w3c = response['status']
        else:
            super(MyWebDriverAppium, self).start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
```

With this you Override the selenium session_id when appium driver creates his selenium driver... So you have all Appium functionality with same session_id

And you can use MyWebDriverAppium with:

```
driver = MyWebDriverAppium('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', self.desired_caps, 'ad6ba37d-4f37-4d11-ba55-15384bd06f5b')
```

Hope it helps someone